# Android layout поверх другого

Tags: android, xml

как можно наложить один layout поверх другого с итемами, чтобы первый перекрывал собой все, что есть?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_Inner"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_InnerClass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="goToNextActivity"
    android:text="Начать"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_InnerClass"
    android:layout_width="268dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="3pt"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"></RelativeLayout >
```

пробовал так поставить, но в итоге кнопка вылазит все равно, хотя textview с посаженным белым текстом не отображается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: честно говоря не очень понятно что вы имеете в виду по словом "перекрывал", элементы должны быть видны, или они должны быть полностью скрыты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задача в том, чтобы `RelativeLayout` покрывал все элементы до него (предполагаем, что внешний элемент для всех трех `view` - `FrameLayout`), то в целом, все работает правильно, что и показывает `TextView`, который прячется под `RelativeLayout` как нужно. Исключение составляет `Button`, почему он показывается поверх и как это исправить можно найти [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017735/incorrect-overlay-behavior-in-framelayout/33018254#33018254). Если кратко, нужно добавить строку к `Button` в XML:

`android:stateListAnimator="@null"`

Comment: спасибо, помогло